# Where to read to understand Woodin's Ultimate-L research

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, set-theory

I have read through most of Kunen's *Set Theory* and a little bit of Jech.  I am familiar with the basics of model theory and forcing.  I am really interested in Woodin's research on investigating Ultimate-L.  However, I don't know too much about what is going on.  I've heard the words inner model, and heard about theorems by Steel and Martin but I don't really know where to learn about this.  What texts or papers should I read to catch up to this?  For example, I don't know too much about large cardinals.

Comment: Woodin has several papers on the topic available, but there is a *lot* of background material assumed; much of the content of Kanamori's *The Higher Infinite* is required.